# Cannot open Kubernetes dashboard page

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to install Kubernetis Cluster with Dashboard on Ubuntu 20.04 TLS  using the following commands:

```
Swapoff -a
Remove following line from /etc/fstab
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0

sudo apt update
sudo apt install docker.io
sudo systemctl start docker
sudo systemctl enable docker

sudo apt install apt-transport-https curl
curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add
echo "deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" >> ~/kubernetes.list
sudo mv ~/kubernetes.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d
sudo apt update
sudo apt install kubeadm kubelet kubectl kubernetes-cni

sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16

mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/k8s-manifests/kube-flannel-rbac.yml


kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.5.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml

kubectl proxy --address 192.168.1.133 --accept-hosts '.*'
```

But when I open `http://192.168.1.133:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:https/proxy`

I get:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "services \"kubernetes-dashboard\" not found",
  "reason": "NotFound",
  "details": {
    "name": "kubernetes-dashboard",
    "kind": "services"
  },
  "code": 404
}
```

I tried to list the pods:

```
root@ubuntukubernetis1:~# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE              NAME                                         READY   STATUS              RESTARTS       AGE
kube-flannel           kube-flannel-ds-f6bwx                        0/1     Error               11 (29s ago)   76m
kube-system            coredns-6d4b75cb6d-rk4kq                     0/1     ContainerCreating   0              77m
kube-system            coredns-6d4b75cb6d-vkpcm                     0/1     ContainerCreating   0              77m
kube-system            etcd-ubuntukubernetis1                       1/1     Running             1 (52s ago)    77m
kube-system            kube-apiserver-ubuntukubernetis1             1/1     Running             1 (52s ago)    77m
kube-system            kube-controller-manager-ubuntukubernetis1    1/1     Running             1 (52s ago)    77m
kube-system            kube-proxy-n6ldq                             1/1     Running             1 (52s ago)    77m
kube-system            kube-scheduler-ubuntukubernetis1             1/1     Running             1 (52s ago)    77m
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper-7bfdf779ff-sdnc8   0/1     Pending             0              75m
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper-8c47d4b5d-2sxrb    0/1     Pending             0              59m
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-5676d8b865-fws4j        0/1     Pending             0              59m
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-6cdd697d84-nmpv2        0/1     Pending             0              75m
root@ubuntukubernetis1:~#
```

Do you know how I can fix the issue?

Comment: dup https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/16335/cannot-start-kubernetis-dashboard

Comment: Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: start by fixing the SDN. I completed my answer on devops.stackexchange.com. As long as SDN is down, Pods that do not use `hostNetwork` can't be started.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/16335/cannot-start-kubernetes-dashboard). Posting the solution here for the benefit of community members.

The URL you're querying (http://192.168.1.133:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:https/proxy ) is wrong.

According to the last yaml file you applied (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.5.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml ), and as we could guess from your kubectl get pods -A: the kubernetes-dashboard Service is located in the kubernetes-dashboard namespace. Not the default namespace.

Although if you just want to connect kubernetes dashboard: instead of the `kubectl proxy` command you run, I would go with `kubectl port-forward -n kubernetes-dashboard deploy/kubernetes-dashboard 8443:8443`, then open my browser to `https://localhost:8443`

Then, there's the case of your SDN. In your `kubectl get pods`, we can see the kube-flannel pod, in kube-flannel namespace, is in Error.

Look at the logs for this container, and try to figure out why it does not start (kubectl logs -n kube-flannel kube-flannel-ds-xxxx -p).

It's been years I didn't setup flannel, although I remember that in addition to applying their RBAC & daemonsets yamls, I also had to patch nodes, allocating them with a CIDR. Eg: `kubectl patch node my-node-1 -p '{ "spec": { "podCIDR": "10.32.3.0/24" } }' --type merge` (each podCIDR must be unique, each node would have its own range hosting Pods.

If I'm not mistaken, each podCIDR must be a subset of flannel's net-conf.json Network subnet -- look at the ConfigMap created while installing flannel).

And as of your last comment: the error tells us the following

```
Failed to create SubnetManager: error retrieving pod spec for 'kube-flannel/kube-flannel-ds-f6bwx': pods "kube-flannel-ds-f6bwx" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-flannel:flannel" cannot get resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "kube-flannel"
```

Looking back at the files you've used setting up flannel, you mentioned that one, that setups workloads in the kube-flannel namespace, then this rbac one, creating a clusterrolebinding for a serviceaccount in kube-system. To fix your SDN, you may want to create the following:

```
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: flannel-fix
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: flannel
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: flannel
    namespace: kube-flannel
```

And for the record: the kube-flannel-rbac is not necessary in your case. It would be, had you installed flannel from their legacy manifest (https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/k8s-manifests/kube-flannel-legacy.yml).

In your case, that ClusterRoleBinding we're fixing should have been created properly, only applying https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml